# Rendering performance: style attributes or classnames and stylesheet rules?

Tags: html, css, performance, browser, svg

I'm building a data visualisation, and the rendering performance is critical. My question would be relevant to bog-standard HTML, though I happen to be using SVG, with JavaScript.

OK, a hypothetical scenario: say I have 10,000 DOM nodes with a `background-color` of "`red`", and 10,000 DOM nodes with a `background-color` of "`green`". Each node is created by a JavaScript loop. I could either:

1. Set a `style` attribute on each node, specifying the `background-color` of the node: `<element style="background-color:red;"/>`
2. Set a `class` attribute on each node, and then reference that class in an inline style or external stylesheet:

   `<head><style>.foo {background-color:red;}</style></head>`

   `<body><element class="foo"/></body>`

The performance of *downloading* the code is not at all important here - I'm only interested in the browser's rendering performance. I'm also quite aware that style attributes are not usually so useful or semantic in day-to-day website development, but I have a specific use case here.

I *am* interested in logical answers, but it'd be really useful to hear from anyone has actually tested this or read about someone else's tests (I've searched for information, but found nothing specifically on this).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you do your own benchmark? I suspect that performance will vary drastically between different browsers ...

Comment: I think it's a very specific case and it's much easier to benchmark it yourself in different browsers. My bet is that it won't differ much, but who knows.

Comment: My guess  would be that the `style` solution works fastest, but I would do a real-world benchmark to find out. Shouldn't be too difficult to do, just create 10,000 mock objects

Comment: Yes, fair enough - I will benchmark it. Still curious to stumble on some else's thoughts or research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a performance benchmark for this:
http://jsperf.com/style-element-vs-attr

From initial tests in Firefox and Chrome, it looks like it's around three times as fast to create and render elements that use classNames, rather than style attributes. I was quite surprised by that - I wasn't sure, but expected the opposite.

Comment: I'd take those statistics with a pinch of salt, because it's only measuring the time the javaScript engine takes to complete, rather than the time it may take to render the graphic. Browsers will typically throttle rendering frames anyway. So, even though JSPerf may report a million operations, the browsers might not render faster than 60 frames per second. In other words, browsers will discard events that happen to fast, rather than render them, if a lot is going on graphically, because the user won't notice anyway. This all affects the meaningfulness of perf results on graphical rendering.

Comment: In my tests, using the browser profilers, the results were negligible in 5000 operations, although directly setting the attribute may be marginally faster than using a style (which is intuitive), using IE and Chrome. It was an unscientific and inconclusive test, but I'm going with that.

Comment: Why is it surprising? Browser processes className CSS rule only once, whereas it has to do it each time when it encounters style in an attribute. Furthermore browser might keep in cache already processed CSS file (if you use external CSS file) and  on repeated view style calculations might be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

I would be extremely surprised if there is a significant difference (and even more surprised if it ever mattered) but if there was one it would be in IE so bench that.

That said, the conditions you are testing are so edge case that I do not think you should be abusing your markup to attain a small-to-insignificant performance benefit in the event that inline was faster. Class based CSS is immeasurably better for the purposes of development and maintenance and semantics and you should avoid inline styles at all costs.

Comment: I would go with 'class' if there are many nodes. Memory usage ought to be lower for this case, which usually is a good thing.

Comment: @Erik: /concur - I can't think of any reason why style would be better and several why it's worse.

Answer (score 0):

If you say, each node is created within a JavaScript loop, isn't that already demanding on browser performance(JavaScript Engine)?

Somehow, I'd be slightly more comfortable setting the colors via JavaScript itself. Say, `$(this).css('color','red');` rather than adding a class which then requires the browser to lookup the computed styles available at the time the script is running and then render/re-render the color change.

I'm not sure if I'm completely right, just an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

After compare the result, I'll stick for using CSS-in-JS solutions, I've tried many, and finally using this lib:

https://github.com/cssobj/cssobj

It's create and update CSS Rules from JS, and it's small in size.